# Cannot Access Shared Contacts Folder In Outlook 2010 VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Im creating outlook add-in and I am having problems getting into Shared folder using vb.net.

I have tried

```
contactsFolder = ns.Folders.Item("Shared Contacts")
```

and

```
contactsFolder = ns.Folders.Item("Public Folders")
```

still have no way of accessing it. can someone help me please. I keep getting error:

```
The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a shared folder, the folder must not exist in the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175604%28v=office.12%29.aspx) [`Store`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176405%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You probably need to enumerate [`Session.Stores`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175607%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (*`ns.Stores`*). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12055323/175679) for code example.

Comment: Yes, You are correct i think. But for some reason the Mail, Calendar and Contacts Tabs are not displaying when I loop through Stores. The Shared Contacts are under Contacts Tab.

Comment: If this is a delegate access scenario, you can try using [`Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219908(v=office.12).aspx). You could also try [`Session.AddressLists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219982(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I'm trying that. I created recipient and tried to get to the folder using GetSharedDefaultFolder but it still errors on me: The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again. If the problem persists, reinstall.

Comment: What is the **Location** (*i.e. folder path*) of `Shared Contacts`? You can find this by right clicking the `Shared Contacts` folder and selecting **Properties**.

Comment: It does not give me the folder path. Its shared contacts of some other user.

Comment: for some reason outlook does not look in exchange to resolve recipient. I have to add to my personal contacts for it to resolve but that starts giving me other errors. what can that be?