# Can't search delegated Inbox

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I have Exchange 2010 server and Outlook 2010 local clients. Some users have delegated the access to their Inboxes to their assistants. It all worked well until recently, without any warning or other issues manifesting my users can't search inside delegated folders. They can access the Inbox and do everything except searching. 
When trying to search following message pops up: An attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.
The logs show nothing more than this message.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Cannot Access Shared Contacts Folder In Outlook 2010 VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097495/cannot-access-shared-contacts-folder-in-outlook-2010-vb-net) where a similar issue is described.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev - your comment is not even in the same ballpark as the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an update glitch. Uninstall all instances of KB2956128.