# Creating a macro in outlook to export subfolders to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to post this here before reaching out to a developer.

Is it at all possible to create a macro in VB that when I run it would export all subfolders in a mailbox and export these messages (or just from email address) and the name of the folder to excel?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: When you mention "subfolders in a mailbox", do you mean that you are working with Outlook?

Comment: Yes, sorry!  I meant in outlook I have 25 sub folders that I need to export mail from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Outlook has an object model that allows vba to find folders, mail messages within folders and mail properties (e.g. message or email address).

- Find folders - [Use Folder Path String to select folder in VBA in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046884/use-folder-path-string-to-select-folder-in-vba-in-outlook)
- Find items in folders - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176540(v=office.12).aspx
- Mail object properties - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176688(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: That is amazing, thank you!  My VBA skills are extremely limited, would this be something I could hire a developer to put together for me?

Comment: Yes, that should only be a few hours work. It wouldn't be difficult for you to do it yourself (although if you aren't an experienced programmer it would take longer).